# Automatically truncate numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When doing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6,7])
print a+b
```

of course, there is an error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)

**Is it possible to make that numpy arrays automatically truncate to the smallest size when two arrays of different sizes are added or multiplied?**

*Example: here `a` has length 3 and `b` has length 4, so we automatically truncate `b` to length 3 before doing the addition. Desired result for `a+b`:*

```
[5 7 9]
```

Can this be done by subclassing `np.array`?

*Remark: I would like to avoid to have to **manually** truncate all arrays myself with `a[:3] + b[:3]`. I want to be able to write just `a+b`.*

Comment: Are the arrays always 1D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, to begin with: what you want to do is bad form. Redefining simple operations often causes all manner of headaches. Subclassing np.array for something like this seems like a horrible idea.

With that said, it is possible to do. Here's a naive way to do it:

```
import numpy as np

class truncarray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__( cls, array ):
        obj = np.asarray(array).view(cls)
        return obj
    def __add__( a, b ):
        s = slice(0, min(len(a),len(b)))
        return np.add(a[s],b[s])
    __radd__ = __add__

a = truncarray([1,2,3])
b = truncarray([4,5,6,7])
a_array = np.array([1,2,3])
b_array = np.array([4,5,6,7])
```

Now, let's see how much this has messed up everything:

Adding truncates, as you'd prefer:

```
In [17]: a+b
Out[17]: truncarray([5, 7, 9])
```

Adding a number no longer works:

```
In [18]: a_array+1
Out[18]: array([2, 3, 4])

In [19]: a+1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-fdcaab9110f2> in <module>()
----> 1 a+1

<ipython-input-2-3651dc87cb0e> in __add__(a, b)
      4                 return obj
      5         def __add__( a, b ):
----> 6                 s = slice(0, min(len(a),len(b)))
      7                 return np.add(a[s],b[s])
      8         __radd__ = __add__

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

When considering a mixture of truncarrays and arrays, addition is no longer transitive:

```
In [20]: a+b_array+a_array
Out[20]: truncarray([ 6,  9, 12])

In [21]: b_array+a+a_array
Out[21]: truncarray([ 6,  9, 12])

In [22]: b_array+a_array+a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-bcd145daa775> in <module>()
----> 1 b_array+a_array+a

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)
```

In fact, it isn't even associative(!):

```
In [23]: a+(b_array+a_array)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-413ce83f55c2> in <module>()
----> 1 a+(b_array+a_array)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (3,)
```

At the very least, if you do this, you'll want to add handling for differing types. But please consider Anton's answer: it's the far safer way of doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You could slice both arrays to the smaller one and then add them:

```
min_size = min(a.size, b.size)
c = a[:min_size] + b[:min_size]
print(c)
array([5, 7, 9])
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to do it manually you could write a function:

```
def add_func(*args):
    to_trunc = min(map(len, args))
    return np.sum([arg[:to_trunc] for arg in args], axis=0)

print(add_func(a,b))
[5 7 9]
```

Comment: Of course, this works but (I should have mentioned this in question) I want to do this *without* having to **manually** truncate all arrays. (in my code, I have many arrays, and I would like to avoid to have to truncate manually like you suggest)

Comment: Sorry, but what I want is to *redefine* the `+` operator such that it automatically truncates and allows using `a+b`. (Thus subclassing `np.array` might be needed)